# How to create new databases and collections when using MongoDB with Docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new with Dockers and now practiced with initializing new MongoDB container using docker-compose.
I've learned that inserting environment variables into the Dockerfile will create for me an admin user and set a password. I also found that I can pass the docker a js file that will process some commands and create for me the structure I want to use.

I tried to create new JS file and write into it some Mongo instructions but faced this error everytime I ran it:

`mongo-1  | 2017-06-10T12:28:08.153+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo_setup.js:1:4`

My JS looks like that:

```
use admin;
db.auth('admin', 'somepassword');
use newDB;
db.createCollection('newCol');
newCol = db.getCollection('newCol');
newCol.insert({'hello':'world'});
```

What did I do wrong? How can I set "newDB" and "newCol" when I run the docker? How can I add some Indexes into the newCol collection automatically?

A little note: I will have to create some DBs and Collections, and initiate all of them by the environment variables is not possible..

Thanks ahead!

Comment: The `use` statements are not actually scripting commands but are interactive. Use statements like `db.getSiblingDB('admin');` Same goes for things like `show collections`. See [Scripting for MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the database you can use scripting using:

```
mongo test --eval "load(youscript.js)"
```

The scritps will be in */data/db* folder